# how to ignore case on sql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, db2

i have this sql query:

```
var userLogin = "select * from login where USERNAME = ?";
```

the problem is, some of the usernames are `testDummy123@gmail.com`, but users may enter it as `testdummy123@gmail.com`, so I just want to ignore the upper or lowercase in general and do one query that says no matter the uppercase or lower case, look for it anyways.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may lowercase both sides of the equality check on the username:

```js
var userLogin = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE LOWER(USERNAME) = ?";
```

To the `?` placeholder, you would bind the lowercase version of the username variable:

```js
var username = "testDummy123@gmail.com";
username = username.toLowerCase();  // bind this variable to ?
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
where lower(username) = lower(?)
```

However, you might be better off using a case-insensitive collation for this purpose.  That would make it easier for the code to use indexes.  Or, ensure that the `username` is stored as lower-case, so you can use:

```
where username = lower(?)
```

which is also index-compatible.